# Class toggles once despite being set to remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click the image within the div it will toggle its class once, which I do not want it to do at all, I just want it to toggle the class of the parent div. How can I stop it from toggling all together?

```js
// .item
function swap() {
    $('#' + event.target.id).toggleClass('selected');

  }
  // .boop

function swapDad() {
  var par = $('#' + event.target.id).parent().attr('id');
  $('#' + par).toggleClass('selected');
  $('#' + event.target.id).removeClass('selected');

}
```

```css
#itemz {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.item {
  margin: 5px;
  border: white 3px solid;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 125px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
}
.selected {
  border: green 3px solid;
}
.boop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itemz">
  <div class="item" id="1" onclick="swap()">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/000/fff?text=test" class="boop" onclick="swapDad()" id="img1">Something
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="2" onclick="swap()">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/000/fff?text=test2" class="boop" onclick="swapDad()" id="img2">Something
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no point in doing `$("#" + event.target.id)`. You don't need to search for an ID when you have the element in a variable, use `$(event.target)`. Also, you need to add the `event` argument to the function definition and function call.

Comment: You should avoid the `onlick` attribute on your html-elements, use proper event-listeners isntead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the image, the click event also propagates to the DIV that contains it, so it's calling `swapDad()` and then `swap()`. If you just want to toggle the class of the DIV, you don't need to have `onclick="swapDad()"` in the `img`.

And instead of using the global variable `event`, which is non-standard and not available in all browsers, you should pass the element as an argument to the function.

```js
// .item
function swap(div) {
    $(div).toggleClass('selected');
}
```

```css
#itemz {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.item {
  margin: 5px;
  border: white 3px solid;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 125px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
}
.selected {
  border: green 3px solid;
}
.boop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itemz">
  <div class="item" id="1" onclick="swap(this)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/000/fff?text=test" class="boop" id="img1">Something
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="2" onclick="swap(this)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/000/fff?text=test2" class="boop" id="img2">Something
  </div>
</div>
```